# Rails autoloading and gem classes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, autoload

So I've got a gem which contains an ActiveRecord Model

```
# one of 30 or so models used by a suite of applications
class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  # some library code
end

# in Rails app, I want to add some behavior to this model using good old ruby class reopening
class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :active, { where active: true }
end
```

The problem is that my app-native version of this model is only autoloaded thanks to Rails. Since it was loaded by the library and the constant is registered, it will never go to the local model to add the locally defined behavior.

Short of having an initializer with a hard-coded list of requires to the local version of the model, how might I get rails to marry the two definitions of the class to end up with one class that has all the behavior?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution would be to:

In your gem, change the model name to something more generic (MyModelTemplate) and make it abstract:

```
class MyModelTemplate < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.abstract_class = true
  # some library code
end
```

Make your real model inherit MyModelTemplate:

```
class MyModel < MyModelTemplate
end
```